# Query from OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

At the moment I'm using the Overpass API to query from OpenStreetMap using https://overpass-turbo.eu/ but when I use the following code, not all the schools in the area appear on the map (e.g. Holy Cross College doesn't appear).

```
area[name = "Council of the City of Ryde"];
node(area)[amenity = school];
out;
```

Anyone know why this might be the case?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenStreetMap data consists of three basic [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements): nodes, ways and relations. Your query searches only for nodes. Some schools will be mapped as ways and a few others as relations.

You have to change your query in order to search for all three elements:

```
area[name = "Council of the City of Ryde"];
(
node(area)[amenity = school];
way(area)[amenity = school];
relation(area)[amenity = school];
);
out;
```

Alternatively just use the keyword `nwr` to search for all three elements:

```
area[name = "Council of the City of Ryde"];
nwr(area)[amenity = school];
out;
```

If there are still missing schools then either they are mapped with a different [tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) or they are missing in OSM. In the second case feel free to [add them yourself](https://learnosm.org/en/beginner/).